# Batch split images vertically in half, sequentially numbering the output files

Tags: files, imagemagick

I have a folder with scans of a book numbered `001.jpg` through `092.jpg`

The scans have two pages of the book scanned together. What I want is split these by two from the middle vertically and regenerate filenames starting from `001.jpg` to `184.jpg`. So `001.jpg` originally will be split as `001.jpg` and `002.jpg`. To avoid any problems I need to write target files in another directory.

I found out Imagemagick does this though I think I need other tools to manage it for batch processing all these images.

Could somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know imagemagick's command line necessary to split things, but that's also not really a problem here, as you already found a way to do that; I'll use `GraphicsMagick` instead here; the same idea applies, just that I find ImageMagick's command line to be very confusing.

So, what I'd do is the following:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/zsh
# this is a ZSH script. Would probably also work under bash, haven't tried.

targetdir=/home/Plato/newimgs

getwidth=gm identify -format '%w'


for number in {001..092}; do
  infile="${number}.jpg"
  width=$(getwidth) "${infile}"

  leftnum=$((number * 2))
  rightnum=$((leftnum + 1))

  gm convert \
    -crop "50%x100%+0+0" \
    "${infile}" \
    "${targetdir}/${(l:3::0:)leftnum}.jpg"
  gm convert \
    -crop "50%x100%+$((width / 2))+0" \
    "${infile}" \
    "${targetdir}/${(l:3::0:)rightnum}.jpg"  
done
```

Comment: Thanks it worked pretty well..
Is there a way to crop 190 pixels from left and right before splitting image?

Comment: @Plato sure! Just adjust the `-crop` specification; it's `-crop {width}x{height}[+-offsetleft+-offsettop]`. I show how you can do simple calculations in your shell: `$(( width / 2 - 190))` for example would half the image width and subtract 190 pixels.

Comment: I need that 190 pixel gone from left for left image and right from right image though, so the formula will be:

    `-crop "50%x100%+190+0"`
    `-crop "50%x100%+$((width / 2 - 190))"`
right?

Comment: on second thought, these are not correct probably. If we move the offset after getting half, in the first case it'll get 190 pixels from the right image because we move offset 190 pixels not crop 190 pixels more from left. It's the same for the other one. If we do it like this, it'll probably move it left 190 pixels. Isn't that right. Or does it crop with offsets after splitting the image in half? I thought that 50% just gives the width of the image.

Comment: Yeah you'll have to explicitly give the desired width in pixels. You want your right image to still start at half the pixels, but your left at 190.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a more recent version of `ImageMagick` you can batch process the images via the [`magick`](https://imagemagick.org/script/magick.php) command e.g. assuming you're running the command in the target directory (so your original `jpg`s are in a different directory):

```
magick /path/to/*.jpg -scene 1 -crop 2x1@ +repage %03d.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Using imagemagick's `convert`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

inputdir=/path/to/images
outputdir=$inputdir/out
mkdir -p "$outputdir"

cnt=0
for i in "$inputdir/"*.jpg; do
    if convert "$i" -crop 50%x100% "$outputdir/%d.tmp"; then
        printf -v fname '%03d.jpg' $((++cnt))
        mv "$outputdir/0.tmp" "$outputdir/$fname"
        printf -v fname '%03d.jpg' $((++cnt))
        mv "$outputdir/1.tmp" "$outputdir/$fname"
    else
        echo "failed to convert $i" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

I haven't found a way to directly specify the output filenames.