# How to split image vertically with fixed height and overlap, with imagemagic?

Tags: imagemagick

I use `convert -crop 1x4+0+30@ +repage in.png out.png` to split a long image vertically to parts with 30px overlap.

I want to make output parts with a fixed height, like 768px, but `convert -crop 100%x768+0+30@ +repage in.png out.png` cannot working.

How to do this ?

Comment: I hope [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/738633/106650) of mine is helpful. Shows how to split a set of large images.

Comment: It seems I can only use the script way as imagemagic does not have this function build in.

Comment: I'd recommend you don't use imagemagick but graphicsmagick, then.